# count up timer integration

Tags: jquery, timer, count

I am trying to add a count up timer to my code. My current code counts down and after the timer reaches 0 it displays news information to a div. This whole process will go on until the page is closed, but I would like to add a stop feature. Meaning that once this code executes 10 times using a count up timer it will completely stop. I tried doing that with the variable `session` but it doesn't count up from 1 to 10. It starts at 0 and then jumps up randomly to 67 then 210 425 and so on. How can I accomplished this count up timer from 1 to 10 and then stop the script?

```
var cycle = 0;
var session = 0;

function countdown() {
    var min = 60 * 10;
    var max = 60 * 30;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

function search() {
    $.getJSON('terms.php?json', function(data) {
        $('#news_updates').attr("src", data);
    });
}


function update() {
    if (session === 10) {
        alert("done");
    }
    if (cycle === 0) {
        cycle = countdown();
        search();
        $('#countdown').html('<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading picture"/>');
        $('#countup').html(session);

    } else {
        var minutes = Math.floor(cycle / 60);
        var seconds = (cycle % 60);

        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        $('#countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
        cycle--;
    }
    session++;
    setTimeout('update()', 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
setTimeout('update()', 1000);
```

try this:

```
setTimeout(update, 1000);
```

Here's a jsFiddle for this part:

- http://jsfiddle.net/kt2dd/

I also added a return in the `if(session === 0) { ... }`, so it stops completely after 10 runs (i.e. not run another `setTimer` and repeat more then expected).

Comment: thanks for taking a look at this :) there is an issue when the countdown seconds hit "10" the alert appears rather than completely counting down to 0. how would you make the count up only after the timer has completely gone to 0?

Comment: @jeff Don't know if this is what you want, but check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/kt2dd/1/

Comment: how would i set session back to 0 after it has reached 10

Comment: Just put `session = 0;` after `alert('done')` - check this: http://jsfiddle.net/kt2dd/2/